# Right-to-left script with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, right-to-left

Is there any reasonable, generic way (i.e. not only Arabic, or only Farsi) to write RTL LaTeX documents (or even bidi) and compile them with pdfTeX or LuaTex?

In ConTeXt, we can use `\righttoleft{my inline content}`, `\startalignment[righttoleft] my paragraph content \stopalignment` and finally `\setupalign[righttoleft]` for the base direction of the document.

When using the `bidi` package (which only works for XeLaTeX as far as I know), they are `\RL`, `setRL` and `\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}` respectively.

So is there a way, and if so what are the three equivalent commands for pdf/LuaLaTex? The reason I'm asking is that [we're debating](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2191#issuecomment-133739077) what [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) should generate for LaTeX output.

Comment: As far as I know, XeLaTeX is the best choice for documents needing sophisticated multilingual support. Is there a reason `pandoc` needs to generate code for one of the less linguistically-advanced engines? (It is true that XeTeX is not, as I understand it, being actively developed now. Maybe LuaTeX will catch up. But my understanding is that it is not there yet.)

Comment: LuaTeX has also support for text directions, see `\luatexpardir` and `\luatextextdir`.  this is much lower level than what is provided by `bidi` package. there is also [luabidi](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/support/luabidi/tex/luabidi.sty), but I don't know what is it's status

Comment: For `pdflatex` there is [arabi](http://ctan.org/pkg/arabi) package with babel, which provide `\textRL`,  `\selectlanguage{arabic}`, and environment to write right to left text.

Comment: @cfr XeTeX *is* being actively developed.

Comment: @mb21 There is a `luabidi`, albeit very rudimentary, they has `bidi`'s basic commands.

Comment: @SalimBou Good point about `\textRL`; minor note though: the shortcut \textRL` is deprecated because when you load both Arabic and Farsi it uses whichever language was loaded last. Instead, the documentation of [arabi](http://ctan.org/pkg/arabi) says you should use `\AR` for Arabic and `\FR` for Farsi (Persian). (Discovered this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368201/48).)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, I managed to define a few commands that should serve as basic fallbacks for those people that resist XeTeX.

LuaTex:

```
\newcommand{\RL}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT#1\egroup}
\newcommand{\LR}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT#1\egroup}
\newenvironment{RTL}{\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\luatexbodydir TRT}{}
\newenvironment{LTR}{\luatextextdir TLT\luatexpardir TLT\luatexbodydir TLT}{}
```

pdfTex:

```
\TeXXeTstate=1
\newcommand{\RL}[1]{\beginR #1\endR}
\newcommand{\LR}[1]{\beginL #1\endL}
\newenvironment{RTL}{\beginR}{\endR}
\newenvironment{LTR}{\beginL}{\endL}
```

But how to set the base direction to rtl? (i.e. if most/all the text is right-to-left, it should start flowing from the right edge.) Do I really need to wrap the whole document in a giant `\begin{RTL}...\end{RTL}`?