# PDFLaTeX and Arabic, Farsi and other scripts

Tags: pdftex, babel

I'm trying to get LaTeX to print several non-Latin scripts, e.g. Arabic, Farsi, and possibly some others. I'm using PDFLaTeX in TeXstudio.

I've tried using this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368201/289942
but nothing happens or rather, it just doesn't work as it's described there.

My main language is English.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.9in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,farsi,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Giaurs - From Persian \FR{فروشگاه‎}(gâvor)
\end{document}
```

The error tells me: `Unicode character ‎ (U+200E) not set up for use with LaTeX. Giaurs - From Persian \FR{فروشگاه‎}` that `U+200E` is the R to L invisible character, but when I try defining it there's no change.

Is there an option to just pass through non-Latin characters as is?
Any solution as to why this isn't working are appreciated.

Comment: It is _much_ easier to set up non latin scripts with luatex than pdftex, is pdftex really a requirement? Pdftex can not "pass through" anything as it is 8 bit input and 8 bit fonts so can not handle standard Araic fonts at all and requires special mapping to be set up

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, Pdftex (is that the same as PDFLaTeX?) isn't a requirement. How difficult will it be to port all the other stuff in my document to Luatex though? And how would I go about this, including the language stuff?

Comment: It's supposed to "just work" but `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
\end{document}` gives a UTF-8 error inside the arabic setup files which was ... unexpected, let me try the newer babel interface....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read the script so apologies if this is completely messed up, but with lualatex, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelprovide[onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer = HarfBuzz, Scale = MatchLowercase]{Amiri} 

\begin{document}
    Giaurs - From Persian فروشگاه‎ (gâvor)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a `}` missing after `Amirixpdf`? 
If it's not there, it just get `File ended while scanning use of \\bbl@bblfont.`
If I add a `}` I get many errors, the first being: `Package fontspec Error: The font "Amirixpdf" cannot be found. \begin{document}`

I'm using TexStudio and switched the `Default Compiler` to `txs:///lualatex`. Was that correct?

Comment: Great, thanks! But I'm still getting the error about the font not being found. Did I change the compiler the right way? Thanks!!

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 it should be `{Amiri}` (or any other Arabic font you have installed)

Comment: Fantastic, now it works! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: It works as intended now, but it's telling me that `\babelprovide` is an unrecognized command. Is that bad?

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 it can't work and give that error.  You would have to have a very old babel for `\babelprovide` to be undefined, are you sure it says that (don't believe texstudio's summary of errors which is worse than useless, what does the log say)

Comment: It's not throwing an error, but Texstudio can highlight a command, and if you hover over it it tells you that it's unrecognized. It still compiles though, which I always find confusing.

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 that just means your _editor_ can't help with that command for command completion and syntax colouring etc, it has no effect on latex

Comment: ah, good to know, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148038/discussion-between-readerguy42-and-david-carlisle).