# Problem "converting" from PDFtex to Luatex, using Latexmk

Tags: pdftex, luatex, latexmk

Following the recommendation of the kind user in this post: [PDFLaTeX and Arabic, Farsi and other scripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694093/pdflatex-and-arabic-farsi-and-other-scripts)

I switched compilers, from Pdftex to Luatex in order to be able to print non-Latin alphabets, which works.

What doesn't work is my shell script to automatically convert from markdown, via pandoc, to a .tex file, to a PDF via Latexmk. I had this working perfectly, but I don't know how to do it for Luatex.

This was the script:

```
mkdir -p /home/Docs/Notes/{{title}} 
pandoc -r markdown-auto_identifiers -w latex {{file_path:absolute}} -o /home/Docs/Notes/{{title}}/{{title}}.tex --template="/home/Docs/LaTeX/My Templates/Notes/Notes.tex" --lua-filter=/home/Docs/LaTeX/Filters/highlight.lua --lua-filter=/home/Docs/LaTeX/Filters/highlight-period.lua --lua-filter=/home/Docs/LaTeX/Filters/Span.lua --lua-filter=/home/Docs/LaTeX/Filters/Span-period.lua
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "cd /home/Docs/Notes/{{title}} && latexmk -pvc -pdf < /dev/null && latexmk -c && cp {{title}}.pdf /home/Docs/Notes/ && exit; exec bash"
```

I run this from a plugin in Obsidian.md (a markdown editor) that can replace the `{{title}}` variables with the current note, i.e. file, name.

With the above script, I get told:

```
! Package babel Error: The bidi method 'basic' is available only in
(babel)                luatex. I'll continue with 'bidi=default', so
(babel)                expect wrong results.
```

I believe only the part after `gnome-terminal` is relevant, and I tried switching the latexmk command to this: `latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -pdf {{title}}.tex`

With this it compiles a little further, but still get an error, and no PDF is produced.

```
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file '2023-07-24.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to '2023-07-24.pdf'
Biber warning: [177] Biber.pm:130> WARN - The file '2023-07-24.bcf' does not contain any citations!
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [2023-07-24.bcf]
Latexmk: All targets (2023-07-24.pdf) are up-to-date
Rc files read:
  /etc/LatexMk
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/Docs/Notes/': Not a directory
```

My MWE LaTeX Document from the other thread:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelprovide[onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer = HarfBuzz, Scale = MatchLowercase]{Amiri} 

\begin{document}
    Giaurs - From Persian فروشگاه‎ (gâvor)
\end{document}
```

How can I adapt this script to automate the process once again.

Thanks!

Comment: change `-pdf`  to `-pdflua`  see `latexmk --help`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or just `-lualatex`

Comment: @daleif you say "just", I say it means the same and is 2 characters longer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle easier to understand for the user ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`latexmk` will use pdflatex by default (or explicitly via the `-pdf` option on the commandline). You can replace that by `-pdflua` or equivalently `-lualatex`

Comment: Now it seemingly mostly works, as in it's opening a compiled PDF in chromium which is weird because that's not my default PDF viewer at all. Also it's still not copying the new PDF to the desired directory, telling me `Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/Docs/Notes/': Not a directory` which is strange since it *is* a directory.

Comment: In the output listings, latexmk says it had success.  The error message appears to be from the command `cp {{title}}.pdf /home/Docs/Notes/ ` (with presumably a correct substitution for `{{title}}`).  Do you get the same error if you run the commands from the command line instead of a script?   What are the contents of `/home/Docs/Notes/`?

Comment: has `title` got a space in its name?

Comment: sometimes, not always. The one I just tested did not.

Comment: @ReaderGuy42 your cp will fail if `cp {{title}}.pdf /home/Docs/Notes/ ` expands to `cp foo bar.pdf /home/Docs/Notes/ ` it needs quotes around the file name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK; I've added single quotes because the whole script here is already surrounded by quotes. This works now, and correctly compiles it to PDF. However, it's still not copying the resulting PDF to the desired directory and it's opening the PDF in chromium and the terminal isn't exiting. How do I fix all of this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that the file is opened and then the commands to copy the file and exit are never processed. I don't want the PDF to automatically open. How can I do this?

Comment: Figured it out! I need the `-pv-` option as that suppresses the opening of the preview. And then it can copy the file to the directory I want. Also in this case the variable `{{title}}` appears to take care of possible spaces, because if I add in single or double quotes it doesn't work and can't find the file. Without them it works. So the script now reads:
`gnome-terminal -- bash -c "cd /home/Docs/Notes/{{title}} && latexmk -pv- -pdflua < /dev/null && latexmk -c && cp {{title}}.pdf /home/Docs/PDFs/ && exit; exec bash"`