luaotfload fails during compilation but luaotfload-tool doesn't
Goal: compile a document with Arabic symbols in MLA style document.
There is a known issue with luaotfload-tool --find. I applied the fix to the directory indicated by kpsewhich luaotfload.sty and after luaotfload-tool --update --force, the tool is fixed:
$ luaotfload-tool --find="ScheherazadeNew"
luaotfload | resolve : Font "ScheherazadeNew" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/ScheherazadeNew-Regular.ttf"

However, trying to compile this document
$ cat mwe.tex
\documentclass[mla8]{mla}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{ScheherazadeNew}

\begin{document}

\begin{paper}
        Testing
        تجربة
\end{paper}
\end{document}

results in
$ lualatex mwe.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlacls/mla.cls
Document Class: mla 2021/09/14 v1.0 MLA Paper Class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
...
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfusetitle' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 113.

)
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: File not found: "ScheherazadeNew.otf".

! Package fontspec Error: The font "ScheherazadeNew" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

For some reason, luaotfload-tool works, but not lualatex when documentclass is MLA. If I set it to article, it compiles as expected.
Edit: I submitted a bug report for the MLA package.
Edit: this isn't related to Arabic. Same problem goes for other fonts: luaotfload-tool --find="Noto Color Emoji".

I'd recommend editing your bug report to explain that the document compiles OK with article and to attach log files for both versions, but most importantly for the failed one. Also see if it is found by XeTeX. As a workaround, try using the filename. (See fontspec's manual for examples.)

The class loads newtxtext which does some disputable settings.
One is that it sets \defaultfontfeatures in some way that disallows loading other fonts; the other is that it does \setmainfont at begin document.
\documentclass[mla8]{mla}

\defaultfontfeatures{}
\AtBeginDocument{\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262887/4427 (with changes)
\newcommand{\RL}[1]{\begingroup\textdir TRT#1\endgroup}
\newcommand{\LR}[1]{\begingroup\textdir TLT#1\endgroup}
\newenvironment{RTL}{\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\bodydir TRT}{}
\newenvironment{LTR}{\textdir TLT\pardir TLT\bodydir TLT}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{paper}

Some initial text

Testing
\begin{RTL}
     تجربة
\end{RTL}

Testing \RL{تجربة}

\end{paper}

\end{document}



Seems a problem with mla class and the loading of package newtxtext: it looks for the OpenType version and not TrueType.
This works for me:
 \setmainfont{ScheherazadeNew-Regular}[
     Script=Arabic,
     Extension=.ttf]


Now it detects it, but doesn't render it. I tried specifying the extension here with the Emoji font, but it didn't work for some reason.
